# All possible types are narrowed but compiler still complains of missing return

Tags: typescript

I am seeing this error:

> Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.

With this TypeScript code:

```
function decodeData(
  data: string | number[] | ArrayBuffer | Uint8Array,
): string {
  const td = new TextDecoder();
  if (typeof (data) === "string") {
    return data;
  } else if (data instanceof Array) {
    return td.decode(new Uint8Array(data));
  } else if (data instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
    return td.decode(data);
  } else if (data instanceof Uint8Array) {
    return td.decode(data);
  } 
}
```

My understanding is that the compiler will see all my guards cover all potential types of `data`. If I add an "else throw" it's happy.

What have I misunderstood?

Comment: At runtime, if `data` is not any of those that you checked for (this is JAVASCRIPT in the end after all), then your function may return `undefined` and cause undefined/unexpected behavior. You should do the right (safe) thing and `throw` at the end.

Comment: I'm going to [edit] the code to change `data instanceof Array<number>` to just `data instanceof Array`.  You're accidentally using an [instantiation expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) which does not do what you think it's doing.  I mean that `data instanceof Array<string>` would behave exactly the same.  There's no `Array<string>` or `Array<number>` at runtime; just `Array`.  If you had a `string[] | number[]` and tried to narrow with `x instance Array<string>` you'd be sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately a missing feature of TypeScript, requested at [microsoft/TypeScript#21985](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21985).

Even though the compiler is able to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the type of `data` to [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) at the bottom of the function, it doesn't seem to understand that this effectively makes the bottom of the function unreachable and therefore all reachable code paths do indeed return a value.  That is, the compiler has no notion of an "exhaustive" set of `if`/`else` statements.  Until and unless microsoft/TypeScript#21985 is implemented, then, you'll have to work around the problem.

---

The compiler *does* have a notion of an exhaustive `switch` statement, so one workaround for situations like this is to refactor to use `switch` instead.  There's no obvious way to do that for `decodeData()`, so we will skip that.

Another approach is to introduce an assertion function `assertNever()`, which only accepts inputs that have been narrowed to `never`, and which itself unequivocally `throw`s so that the compiler knows that subsequent code is unreachable:

```
function assertNever(x: never): never {
    throw new Error("Unexpected Value: " + x);
}
```

Then, at the end of `decodeData()`, you call `assertNever(data)`:

```
function decodeData(
    data: string | number[] | ArrayBuffer | Uint8Array,
): string {
    const td = new TextDecoder();
    if (typeof (data) === "string") {
        return data;
    } else if (data instanceof Array) {
        return td.decode(new Uint8Array(data));
    } else if (data instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
        return td.decode(data);
    } else if (data instanceof Uint8Array) {
        return td.decode(data);
    }
    assertNever(data);
}
```

That suppresses the "not all paths return a value" error, since `assertNever()` definitely throws, and it also checks for exhaustiveness, since otherwise `assertNever(data)` wouldn't compile successfully:

```
function badDecodeData(
    data: string | number[] | ArrayBuffer | Uint8Array,
): string {
    const td = new TextDecoder();
    if (typeof (data) === "string") {
        return data;
    } else if (data instanceof Array) {
        return td.decode(new Uint8Array(data));
    //} else if (data instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
    //    return td.decode(data);
    } else if (data instanceof Uint8Array) {
        return td.decode(data);
    }
    assertNever(data); // error! 
    // -------> ~~~~
    // Argument of type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
}
```

Here I've commented out one of the cases, and sure enough, `assertNever(data)` complains that `ArrayBuffer` (the missing case) is not a valid `never`.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6oKYCcoDkMBu2AFAB4BciYh2AlJdUVogN4BQiniUAFlnAHcqGIQFEs-LMQBEAVWqkADhmgYAJogBqyADYgMlaYgDUiUrQDcbAL5s2oSLASI1KuK4AiyKMmIcuat7IlKhQWDBgAOaIAD5UIAC2AEbYANoAurGIAIISyACeAEIgwMDYWbIRUAAcuVgFADRs9Iih4VGs-pwQCKHcGgC8wkIAKhikUB5urlKWXYgwwIjEUPnKcEvEgT60iAP7iNJtEZHSu+xcl4hYGFAgWEjbyFaX1ogYOpgLm08LYKHISAYDY5PL5c7zS43O4PfoAOlcPVcxGoQkqYBqdQKWyCtDmr3enww32WvwiAKBIKxRRKZSwEKuXGh9yQUDUCOmGBxOxeXDeHy+i1JQT+FIgwKW6MxYIZjOutxZ8MR7i5T3xfPmaEwOHwTG5yDmtjsDmg8CQSWQaimSIwXh8fkuTxCYROWTAiRSWAyWWpxVK5TiUtqYKaLWOHQuXB6-yg-T2w0QYwm1pVs15nCFKzWEuFOz2ByOLqiZ06cvlMMeQXTiH5RJJ+tFPkpS2pssZzNhbI5NpRIkQQep+rx1cuAHpR7XBT8ReSm+KqWC-XS21dx1CFZ32crkWrq5PiZmyTHAfPJVVg-VwaW5R3WVvOUO95r0Ng8DQpLvEGvsJIAISIeY1wAWhA0CgIAPkQAA-GCoMA0dQUiRIMAxRAQVWZREAAcl9WlsCwhZUCoOBYy1GBIjAZAkh0YkoDgRBFGQeoElucp0OzbDGHwmwgA)

Answer (score 0):

```
function decodeData(
  data: string | number[] | ArrayBuffer | Uint8Array,
): string {
  const td = new TextDecoder();
  if (typeof (data) === "string") {
    return data;
  } else if (data instanceof Array<number>) {
    return td.decode(new Uint8Array(data));
  } else if (data instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
    return td.decode(data);
  } else if (data instanceof Uint8Array) {
    return td.decode(data);
  }

  return '';
}
```

Comment: Sure this pleases the compiler Gods but why is this necessary?

Comment: You are supposed to return a `string` value by default as you defined the function return type, all your return's were in if... else.. statement @LukePuplett

Comment: This is a code-only answer, and should probably be [edit]ed to include an explanation for why this is an appropriate approach, or how it answers the question as asked.  (I don't believe it *does* answer the question)

Comment: Because when all the return statements are inside if blocks it is possible for the method to not return anything. And at the same time the method should return string. Then the last return is some kind of a fallback/insurance that if the if statements miss then the tipisation will be correct again and the method will return a string type.

Comment: @DreamBold that doesn't address the question; see [this code example](https://tsplay.dev/mM8VkN); the `bar()` function has no error, despite the `return`s being only inside `case` statements; there's no `return` at the end, but the compiler knows that the `switch` is exhaustive.  No such exhaustiveness check happens for the equivalent series of `if`/`else` statements.  The question here is *why*?  The answer is that it's a missing feature, requested at [ms/TS#21985](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21985)

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/14giMfO.png It shows an **error**: `Not all code paths return a value.` @jcalz You see it?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/6iC7Nvb.png Switch is something different, I guess.